# Breeze: getting collection of results that are wrapped in meta data object

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am attempting to use Breeze with AngularJS and a Web API back end which returns data in the following format:

### API response format:

```
{
    Count: 123,
    Items: [
        {
            CustomerID: 1,
            FirstName: "John",
            Surname: "Smith",
            // etc.. 
        }, 
        {
            CustomerID: 2,
            FirstName: "Bill",
            Surname: "Jones",
            // etc.. 
        }, 
        {
            // 23 more Customer records...
        }
    ],
    NextPageLink: "http://localhost/web/api/customers?$skip=25"
}
```

I have manually set up the `Customer` entity in the metaDataStore following the example on the Breeze.js website http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-hand-depth:

```
function addCustomer() {
    addType({
        shortName: "Customer",
        defaultResourceName: "customers",
        dataProperties: {
            CustomerID: { type: ID, isPartOfKey: true },
            FirstName: { max: 50 },
            Surname:  { max: 50 },
            // a bunch more properties
       }
    });
}
```

My code to query the "customers" endpoint looks like this:

```
function getCustomers(){
    var customers =  manager.getEntities('Customer');
    return breeze.EntityQuery.from('customers')
        .using(manager).execute()
        .then(function(data){
            return data.results; // breakpoint here is reached
        });
}
```

The query successfully executes, as when I put a breakpoint where indicated, the `data` object is there but the `data.results` property is an array containing what looks like a single `Customer` entity that is empty. See screenshot:

[image: Dev tools contents of data.results]

I suspect that this is due to the fact the the back end is returning the collection as the `Items` property of a wrapper object.

**My question then is:** assuming I am unable to change the response from the back end API, how do I tell Breeze that my `Customer` entities are actually contained in the `results.Items` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own custom `JsonResultsAdapter` to do this.

See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mapping-json for more details.

We also have a [sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/edmunds) that shows a custom adapter in action with a 3rd party back end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I can now get the collection of Customer entities as I wanted. One further question - what is the recommended way to preserve the meta-data `Count` and `NextPageLink`. Currently my `jsonResultsAdapter` just returns `data.results.Items`, so I get my entities, but I lose the metadata. Any further help you can give would be appreciated!

Comment: It's fine - I figured it out myself. The Edmunds example code was very helpful.